# Skipping letters not working when typing letter z

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am having problem when a user types in a letter, then typing how many numbers to be skipped. For example user types in letter abc, then type 2 numbers to be skipped the output is cdf, In my program this is working fine. However when a user types in xyz, then types in number 4. my program doesnt work. Also, all letter having z will not display the output. For example xyz, then number to be skipped is 1 the output will be yz only.

```
public class Test2 {

private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
private char characters[]=     {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
        'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
```

}

Comment: Your `f` loops appears to have no upper bound.  Can you explain what your code is doing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my code will get the letter inputted by a user, then the user will type how many numbers to be skipped. for example I type a, then type 1. the output will be b since a + 1 will be b..but if I type z, and 1 as a number to be skipped there is no output.

Comment: And what should the output be for `z` and `1` to skip?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It should return to a. For example I type letter xam and number 4, the output should be  beq.

Comment: Why did you remove the code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oops sorry I was editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is some sort of modulus functionality, whereby the letter "wraps" around to the start of the alphabet in the event that the offset goes past the letter z.  Try this code:

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (int f=0; f < text.length(); f++) {
    int index = alphabet.indexOf(text.charAt(f));
    System.out.println(alphabet.charAt((index + num) % 26));
}
```

This code snippet was tested on IntelliJ and for input `xam` and `4` gives the correct output `beq`.